# Define Image background is good or bad

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am currently working on image segmentation project for human images. I am trying to find a way where we can check the image and decide that whether image is good for segmentation or not.

For example if a person is wearing a black shirt and background is also black or gray or person is sitting on black chair then image segmentation covers chair also with human.
So is there a way where we can do basic checking about image and give a warning that 'Foreground and background looks to be similar so chances are there that output will be not that good.'

Answer (score 0):

If a human can differentiate between FG & BG, then AI algorithms can too. There are many contrast improvement image-processing algorithms. So don't ask a general question, rather be specific what you need & post with sample data.

Comment: Thanks I totally agree with u, but AI have limitations which human mind don't. There are many things that human mind can do but not by AI.

Question is very simple where I am looking for suggestions for checking the quality of images that can be useful for image segmentation.